# Typesafe generic collection builder / container

Tags: java, generics

Within my method `readList`, I would like to build a `java.util.List` of a user-defined type (the concrete list type is a parameter). I don't want to restrict `readList` to `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` however; the user might supply his own `java.util.List` implementation. The method might also cache the list if possible, so the method needs to return the list. I tried a few things. Which one of the following is the 'best' API in your view, or is there another, even better one?

The following compiles, but I get the compiler warning: "Type safety: The expression of type ArrayList needs unchecked conversion to conform to ArrayList", so it's not really a good solution:

```
void classParameter() {
    ArrayList<String> a = readList(ArrayList.class);
    LinkedList<String> b = readList(LinkedList.class);
}

<X, T extends List<X>> T readList(Class<T> clazz) {
    try {
        return clazz.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

The following compiles, but I still get the compiler warning, plus it doesn't actually work as expected:

```
void classTypeParameters() {
    ArrayList<String> a = readList(ArrayList.class, String.class);
    LinkedList<String> b = readList(LinkedList.class, Integer.class);
}

<T extends List<X>, X> T readList(Class<T> clazz, Class<X> type) {
    try {
        return clazz.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

The following works, and is my personal favorite. It checks the list type. What is a bit dangerous is somebody could by mistake forget to assign the result. This could be solved by renaming `readList` to `readListWithTemplate` or so, it would be more obvious the return value is to be used. It's similar to `List.toArray(T[] a)`:

```
void template() {
    ArrayList<String> a = readList(new ArrayList<String>());
    LinkedList<String> b = readList(new LinkedList<String>());
    // wrong usage:
    List<String> c = new LinkedList<String>();
    readList(c);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
<X, T extends List<X>> T readList(T template) {
    try {
        return (T) template.getClass().newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

The "super token type" works as well, but might be bit hard to understand
for developers not familiar with this pattern, and in Eclipse
I get the warning "Empty block should be documented", which I would like to avoid:

```
void superTypeToken() {
    ArrayList<String> a = readList(new ListType<ArrayList<String>>() {});
    LinkedList<String> b = readList(new ListType<LinkedList<String>>() {});
}

abstract static class ListType<X extends List<?>> {
    // super type token class
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
<X, T extends List<X>> T readList(ListType<T> t) {
    try {
        Type type = t.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        if (!(type instanceof ParameterizedType)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Missing type parameters");
        }
        ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) type;
        type = pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        pt = (ParameterizedType) type;
        Class<?> listClass = (Class<?>) pt.getRawType();
        return (T) listClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Which one do you prefer? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: using guava? `List<SomeThing> list = Lists.newArrayList()`

Comment: @RC The question is not 'how to create an ArrayList'.

Comment: sure but guava `Lists` is the kind of API that is "the 'best' API in [my] view", I don't see why you would need to create something else..

Comment: @RC Maybe you want to read the question again? Specially "the user might supply his own java.util.List implementation" and "The method might also cache the list if possible". Really, I know how to create an ArrayList :-) That's not the question at all here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably delegate to another builder class. A small class that just knows how to create new lists. It provides better runtime safety as it does not rely on the assumption that the given class has a default constructor. Maybe not so useful with lists as we should always be able to create an empty list, but more important with other types of class.

eg.

```
public interface EmptyListBuilder {

    public <E> List<E> newList();

    public static final EmptyListBuilder ARRAY_LIST_BUILDER = 
            new EmptyListBuilder() {

        public <E> List<E> newList() {
            return new ArrayList<E>();
        }
    };
}
```

As shown by the static field you can also provide a default implementation for a few standard classes.

Use the class like this:

```
<T> List<T> readList(EmptyListBuilder builder) {
    List<T> list = builder.newList();
    // read in elements
    return list;
}
```

You lose being able to know exactly what type of list you have, but of that's an issue then it sounds like you're trying to do something a little odd.

Comment: Nice solution, I didn't think about it. Thanks!